# div push down footer when opening accordion?

Tags: html

ie7 is at it again - my accordion works in all other browsers but in ie7 it does not push down the footer, but overlaps it and heads way down the page. Any idea what I can do to make it so that when I open one of the accordions the div expands and pushes down the footer?

Thanks in advance!

jeez sorry. heres the link

```
http://184.172.137.64/~laserlof/temp/services.php
```

Comment: A link to your site, or a jsfiddle is required in order to be able to help.  Without seeing your code, it's impossible to know what's going on, since the issue is likely due to the html structure of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is a pain that way. I would suggest having the div display in a block and adding either padding or a margin to the bottom of it. I have this on one of my sites and it pushes the footer down in IE:

```
div {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Edit:

Ok remove the height: 100% on the accordian id in your css

You have this in your css somewhere

```
    #accordion {
      float:left;
      height:100%;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      position:relative;
      width:950px;
    }
```

If you remove the

```
   height:100%;
```

it will allow the accordion to expand properly

Comment: How can you answer the questions without knowing a single line of code?

Comment: Have you tried to set the css to target IE7 only and use !important after the setting?

Comment: The issue is fixed in Firefox but for some reaosn IE7 didn't respond. Maybe I'm missing a bit of information - but if I'm deleting height 100%, (which I did) I don't know what to put !important after. I did a target to IE7 with Height:auto !important, but that didn't work. IE7 is a pain!

Comment: I figured it out, the page wrap for ie7 only needed height:100%. the accordion wrap for firefox needed height:100% deleted. crazy.